# Using SSH to execute a command - $PATH is fine but running perl scripts fails?

Tags: linux, perl, ssh, execution

**Going from a Linux host to another Linux host**

Say I run:

`ssh user@server ' . /etc/profile; /path/to/myScript.pl'`

I always get errors involving scripts within that perl script like...

`/path/to/otherscript.sh was not found No Such File or Directory`

-even though it's obviously there. Running this script locally on "server" works just fine. What's also confusing is that the output of....

`ssh user@server ' . /etc/profile; echo $PATH'`

...looks EXACTLY the same as `echo $PATH` when running on "server" locally.

Any ideas as to why this is not working? I do not have permissions to modify the perl script to always* include the complete path to the files listed.

**if it's useful** this is running with a shebang of #!/usr/bin/env perl - reading up on it now, would this alter my path?**

Comment: Did you test this on a server also with sourcing the profile first?

Comment: Lots of things that *could* be at issue, none of which you're provided enough info to debug. Maybe we need a `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to find shared libraries used by the perl interpreter. Maybe the shebang starts with `#!/usr/bin/env` and we thus care about `PATH`. Maybe there's SELinux instrumentation at play configured to only allow specific commands to be invoked without an interactive shell as parent. Maybe your script has DOS newlines, so it's trying to run a file named `/path/to/myScript.pl$'\r'` (which doesn't exist, for obvious reasons) remotely.

Comment: Actually, if that last one is it, `ssh user@server 'set -x; . /etc/profile; /path/to/myScript.pl'` may be informative, at least if you have a new enough bash (4.x should be fine) to print that unambiguously on the remote end.

Comment: thanks for the 'set -x' tip I hadn't thought to use that, however it looks like the results are virtually identical (diff'd the outputs and everything) for both

no DOS newlines I've checked that also - BUT I can tell you that the shebang of the perl script does start with /usr/bin/env - what would this imply for me trying to run it remotely? PATH appears the same on both - does it briefly get changed for the script?